# How to generate UUID version 4 using c#

Tags: c#, google-maps, uuid, guid

My requirement is to generate version 4 UUID from C# code for google API session token and i am not sure `Guid.NewGuid()` method, Which version of GUID does it return. Like version

Read google and blog but not get sure answer 
[Does Guid.NewGuid() produce UUID version 4 according to RFC4122?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4956142a-0a5d-4f1e-b102-93a3eea1b5d5/does-guidnewguid-produce-uuid-version-4-according-to-rfc4122?forum=netfxbcl)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I read through the blog , strangely Microsoft stops short in giving it in writing that Guid.NewGuid() will generate a UUID v4 guid. Perhaps could be a legal obligation. Anyways I think there is a pretty good implementation available here https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/uuid-rfc4122.html please see if this works for you..

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee: Thanks friend for the help

Answer (score 29, accepted):

GUIDs are V4... every single GUID you generate will look like this

```
18acac20-991e-437e-9529-a441452f6b7e
d6d68639-64c2-452e-95b7-16cf6dbf5301
b0943b6d-4779-4771-92bf-cc2d634fb671
218b5620-d30d-46d9-9c88-38a4ac64266e
de03042c-792f-4689-80ca-26287ceb2129
1175bb5d-d35e-4a46-aaac-0825c749dc3a
42864583-c0f6-4e44-8710-39c9a9146d43
223ca924-4b77-4931-bb94-c1d371894683
2c4495ab-19e4-4aeb-b647-10db8625791c
f5894345-cbe3-4fc7-92c3-d6d863f70411
              ^    ^
              1    2
```

The digit at position `1` above is always `4` and the digit at position `2` is always one of `8`, `9`, `A` or `B`.

You can confirm this by

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8, CancellationToken = cts.Token };
Parallel.For(0, int.MaxValue, parallelOptions, (i) =>
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var four = guid.ElementAt(14);
    var ab89 = guid.ElementAt(19);

    if (four != '4') cts.Cancel();
    if (ab89 != 'a' && ab89 != 'b' && ab89 != '8' && ab89 != '9') cts.Cancel();

    if ((i % 100000) == 0 && i < (int.MaxValue / 8))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i * 8:n}"); // roughly   
    }
});
```

That will run through 4billion'ish attempts in a reasonable amount of time if you have doubts

Comment: Do I send the Guid as is? with/without dashes or other identifying characters? In Google doc they just write 123456789 as session token....

Comment: There's discussion about this here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4956142a-0a5d-4f1e-b102-93a3eea1b5d5/does-guidnewguid-produce-uuid-version-4-according-to-rfc4122?forum=netfxbcl

He got Microsoft to investigate and their GUID implementation _happens_ to be UUIDv4, but they don't guarantee it won't change in the future. If it changes they will ensure it's non-colliding and note the change in the MSDN documents.

Comment: @o_w Generally you should use UUIDs as either formatted hex strings with the dashes _OR_ a 16 byte number. It's not clear what "Google Doc" you're looking at, but using 32 characters without the dashes is not something I would recommend.

Comment: FWIW the current Microsoft documentation promises to use RFC 4122 at least for .Net Framework 4 and up.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.0